# Check whether object exists in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, apriori

I am brand new to R, so please excuse anything that may seem overly obvious.

I am using apriori to evaluate frequent item sets.  When I execute the code below and my subset call returns items, everything works great.  The problem is when there is nothing returned on the subset (the criteria returns no subset).  When it does this, I am receiving "object 'rulesMatchLHS' not found" when trying to construct a data frame for output.  Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong when checking the validity of rulesMatchLHS on the ifelse line?

```
rules <- apriori(trnew, parameter=list(supp=0.01, conf=0.5, minlen=2, maxlen=2))
rulesMatchLHS <- subset(rules, lhs %ain% dataset1)
ifelse(exists(rulesMatchLHS), 
OutputClient <- data.frame(lhs=labels(lhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements, rhs=labels(rhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements,rulesMatchLHS@quality),
OutputClient <- data.frame())
View(OutputClient)
```

Comment: I don't which package is that, but I think there is a typo in `%ain%`, maybe it should be `%in%`. Ifelse part maybe like this `OutputClient <- ifelse(exists(rulesMatchLHS), 
                       data.frame(lhs=labels(lhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements, 
                                                         rhs=labels(rhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements,
                                                         rulesMatchLHS@quality),
                       data.frame())`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It is the arules package.  I am receiving the same error with that code as well.  The exists(rulesMatchLHS) is throwing the error.  Essentially, I cannot execute rulesMatchLHS anywhere without it throwing that error.

Comment: Hard to say without reproducible example. I think you should use if not ifelse: `if(exists(rulesMatchLHS)){
  OutputClient <- data.frame(lhs=labels(lhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements, 
             rhs=labels(rhs(rulesMatchLHS))$elements,
             rulesMatchLHS@quality)
}else{
  OutputClient <-data.frame()
}`

Answer (score 0):

Subset returns an empty data frame.  So it does exist. Also exists requires that the parameter be a character string.  You might want to change the exists to nrow in your ifelse.  Here is a simple example to demonstrate:

```
test <- subset(iris, Species == "Fake")
typeof(test)
exists("test")
nrow(test) == 0
```